# RStudio Exporting Issues

Tags: r, plot, export

I have never really needed to export anything from RStudio with specific dimensions. Now I am producing some graphs for a publication with a strict width of 2400 pixels. My major problem is that I have not used a singular traditional plot for what I have done. I have really customised my graph with various plots and segments. To evaluate the plot as I have been making it, I have been looking at the zoomed in plot in RStudio.

So What I am asking is whether there was a way I could export exactly that zoomed in plot on RStudio to a png with the specified width (height, I am fairly flexible with).

I have tried

```
dev.copy2pdf(device = "pdf", file = "test.pdf")
```

Which didn't work as I had hoped.

Comment: don't think so. you can open up the export box and drag the image around in there. or drag the actual rstudio panels, that will change the device. or maybe take a screenshot, but that won't be a pdf

Comment: What plotting system are you using?  Base?  ggplot?

Comment: I was using base plot. I would recommend to anyone else who may find themselves in a similar situation to me, just disregard the plot the window in RStudio produces. Specify your dimensions if you know they need to be exact before starting and just make sure that the exported file is some how really easy and efficient to open and check it each time you adjust something. You won't find yourself coming to the end of a project and having major difficulties producing a final piece of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ggplot, you can use ggsave:

```
qplot(rating, data=movies, geom="histogram")
ggsave("test.pdf", height=8, width=8)
```

The default DPI is 300 so 300 DPI x 8 inches = 2400.

This should do the same in the base plotting system:

```
pdf("boxplot.pdf", height=8, width=8)
boxplot(mtcars$mpg)
dev.off()
```

Comment: When you specify both height and width as arguments to ggsave, do you not run the risk of distorting the output pdf if the original plot is not square?  Can't you just specify width = 8 and let the other aspect adjust?

Comment: Yes.  You could specify only the width.